# Remote desktop forced logoff

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I use remote desktop quite a bit and I've noticed that on one of my machines when another user is already logged in it prompts them to allow me to log in, even for users with less privileges; however, with another computer, there is no prompt, it just proceeds with the remote logoff even for users with the same privileges. Both computers are XP professional SP3.

What could be causing this, and how (if possible) can I set this?

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I already know about other tools such as VNC and I use them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is a "feature" of fast user switching. After turning it off I am now able to remote desktop in without the user prompt.

[Screen Shot http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vxel2&s=4](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vxel2&s=4)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed I suggest where VonC already mentioned, but more specifically: gpedit.msc, Computer/User configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Terminal Services -> Connections -> *Set rules for remote control of Terminal Services user sessions*

Comment: In Windows 7, the group policy path is a bit different: `Computer/User configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Connections -> Set rules for remote control of Remote Desktop Services user sessions`.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server editions support one console plus two remote connections simultaneously.  When configured as a Terminal Server, they support one per license.  All other editions support one total session, local or remote.

Are the pre-existing connections local or Domain accounts? Look around in the local or group security policies.  If Domain, check the user account properties.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that; however, my question is really about the prompting of the currently logged on user.

Comment: I missed the second paragraph, sorry. I will check that out.

Comment: Not entirely correct. I can support multipile connections with Windows XP using a hack on the terminal services dll and a change to a registry key.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compare the policies or settings between the computer for:

- Terminal Services policies (type 'gpedit.msc', then Computer configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Terminal Services)
- Terminal Service (type 'services.msc'), which depends on 'Fast User Switching Compatibility' service: is this one activated on the 'other' computer ?